# Model is set as only readable Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to using Angular and Typescript, and currently working on supporting a project, so my task is to create a service and show data added to DOM (with no refreshing it).

So I create the call on the component as:

**TS:**

```
export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() profile: ProfileModel;

    addSalary() {
        let salary: SalaryModel = {
          clientId: 1,
          profileId: this.profile.id,
          amount: this.salary.value,
          startDate: new Date(),
          endDate: null,
        }
          this.apiService.profileService.addSalary(salary).subscribe(p=>{
            this.apiService.profileService.getProfile(this.profile.id).subscribe(pc=>{
            debugger;
            this.profile.salaries = pc.salaries;
            this.resetDataForm()
          });
          });
      }
  }
```

**Model**

```
export class ProfileModel {
// code here
 salaries: SalaryModel[];
}
```

**Html**

```
<li *ngFor="let salary of profile.salaries; let i=index">
  //code here
</li>
```

The method works well on the API, but it throws an error when I assign the model after the debugger on:  `this.profile.salaries = pc.salaries;.`

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'salaries' of object
> '[object Object]'

I tried to set the object writable as:

```
Object.defineProperty(this.profile.salaries, 'salaries', {
          writable:true
       });

        this.profile.salaries = [{...pc.salaries}]
```

But I got the same error; how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you create SalaryModel, but I will try to help another way.

If you wont to sent some data to low level component - don't change props of inputs in low level component. It's not normal data stream. Use low level component like dump components: send in at @Input and send out at @Output (like "clear functions"). More info about two way data binding - https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

If you have some "state" of some data - use state management patterns (like NGXS) or custom service state manager.